# .NET Core 3 Docker Project Generates Too Many 307 Redirects Before Failing

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, .net-core

When launching an application deployed to Google Application Engine Flexible, it fails with too many 307 redirects. It runs successfully locally in the VS IDE.

The development and computing stack include:

- MacOS
- .NET Core 3
- Visual Studio 2019 for Mac
- Docker
- Google Application Engine

I created a project using the VS api template (weather forecast).

- Create API project
- Add Docker support (via the menu)
- Create and export SSL certificate:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -v -ep /Users/QQQQQQQ/Projects/CostZzzzzzzzzz/xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost/Certificate/dev-certificate.pfx -p ufo
```

(which i subsequently moved to root of project)

- Modify Dockerfile as follows:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
    WORKDIR /app
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443
    EXPOSE 8080

    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    COPY Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost/Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost.csproj Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost/
    RUN dotnet restore "Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost/Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost.csproj"
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost"
    RUN dotnet build "Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
    ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080;https://*:443
    ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
    ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost/dev-certificate.pfx
    ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=ufo
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Xxxxx.Orchestration.Cost.dll"]
```

- Create app.yaml

```
    runtime: custom
    env: flex

    # This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
    # The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
    # for production use. For more information, see:
    # https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
    manual_scaling:
      instances: 1
    resources:
      cpu: 1
      memory_gb: 0.5
      disk_size_gb: 10

    network:
        name: default
        subnetwork_name: default-us-east1

    service: get-cost

    env_variables:
      # The __ in My__Greeting will be translated to a : by ASP.NET.
      My__Greeting: Hello AppEngine Flex!
```

- Modify Program.cs to support kestrel and ssl

```
     public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(options =>
             {
                 //     //options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);  // http:localhost:5000
                 options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 8080);         // http:*:80
                 options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 443, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.UseHttps("dev-certificate.pfx", "ufo");
                    });

             })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

- Deploy service to GAE: gcloud app deploy

This solution is the conflation of several articles describing how to create and deploy .NET Core applications to GAE via Docker.

The error log's primary message is:
XXX.YYY.ZZZ.AAA - "GET /" 307 undefined "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"

I am looking for help on how to properly configure the application so that it will run correctly in the GAE.

PS: By removing the ENV instructions in the Dockerfile, the docker container will run locally on my mac. However, running it on the GAE has eluded me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was quite simple once i understood what the real problem was, part of which stemmed from being quite new to the newer .net core versions such as 3.x, being new to GAE Flex, and to Docker, all at the same time.

In any event, removing app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in the Startup.cs class' Configure method resolved the immediate problem. The issue was explained in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Essentially GAE Flex was already providing redirection on port 8080, so the additional redirection instruction in the code was causing endless redirections with HTTP 307 results.

Comment: Hi @tonyatl, good work finding the solution! Can you [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!